# Cannot Resolve Symbol 'turbolinks'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols, turbolinks

I'm doing a rails tutorial. turbolinks is installed and updated and all that and it's in the gemfile but in app/assets/javascripts/application.js it's coming up with an error saying it can't resolve the symbol. The github repository is at https://github.com/torin555/sample_app if you want to have a closer look.

Comment: did you restart your app?

Comment: You mean restart the server? Well yes but that wouldn't do anything since the gem has been installed for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove turbolinks ... let me clone your project!

I have cloned your project and have a different error.

Could you please let me know if the git is upto date and what URL you are on?

Thanks!

Comment: Removing it isnt really an option... I'm doing a tutorial.

Comment: I just installed your sample_app and I am getting this error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in StaticPages#home

Comment: What error are you getting I am not going to write your app for you.

Comment: I havent been following tests. they were broken

Comment: git is up to date. Im on localhost:3000

Comment: and Im on chapter 8 not 9

Comment: I dont know why you are getting a different message... @Tyler

Answer (score 0):

Alright. installed the proper version of execjs and it worked.